# can't get autocomplete popup box to disappear on onblur

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete form as shown here:
http://res.nodstrum.com/autoComplete/

I can't get onblur to work and make the suggestions box disappear.

I've included a lot of code for completeness below but the important parts are the HTML and maybe fill().

I've tried

```
onblur="document.getElementById('suggestions').style.display='none';"
```

and tried

```
$('#suggestions').hide();
```

in `fill()`

amongst others but just can't get it to work.

**HTML**

```
<form>
        <div>
            Type your country:
            <br />
            <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" onFocus="this.value=''; this.onfocus='';" value="France"/>
        </div>

        <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
            <img src="upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;" alt="upArrow" />
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function lookup(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
} // lookup

function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#inputString').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
```

This is the crux of rpc.php

```
if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
            // Run the query: We use LIKE '$queryString%'
            // The percentage sign is a wild-card, in my example of countries it works like this...
            // $queryString = 'Uni';
            // Returned data = 'United States, United Kindom';

            // YOU NEED TO ALTER THE QUERY TO MATCH YOUR DATABASE.
            // eg: SELECT yourColumnName FROM yourTable WHERE yourColumnName LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10

            $query = $db->query("SELECT your_column FROM your_db_table WHERE your_column LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
            if($query) {
                // While there are results loop through them - fetching an Object (i like PHP5 btw!).
                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                    // Format the results, im using <li> for the list, you can change it.
                    // The onClick function fills the textbox with the result.

                    // YOU MUST CHANGE: $result->value to $result->your_colum
                    echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->value.'\');">'.$result->value.'</li>';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
            }
        }
```

Comment: in which element you are putting `onblur` ??

Comment: the onblur is in the first div, where the input is so that if they don't choose something from the suggestions box, and then click on something else on the page, the suggestions box disappears.

Comment: ohh okk ... `div` doesnt support `onblur event` directly..
try putting `tabindex=0` in your div...
it will be like
`<div tabindex="0">`.. after doing this it should work....

Comment: Sorry I meant in the onblur is in the input tag which is in the first div.

Comment: ohhk.. you have put `thisvalue` instead of `this.value` a dot is missing there.. try removing `thisvalue` from your `fill()` function.
just put `fill()` instead of `fill(thisvalue)`....

Comment: fill is triggered from rpc.php and needs thisvalue in the function.  For some reason standard onblur wipes the clicked value from the list. Tried what you said and still couldn't get it to work.  For something that should be easy is becoming a real pain.

Comment: do you use `firebug` in `mozilla firefox` it will show you the `javascript error`.. 
here is the link
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48245/discussion-between-user2484214-and-nishant-solanki)